# Corona SDK: touch event

Tags: sdk, lua, touch, coronasdk

How can I detect if screen is being touched? Seems to me, touch events are not generated while screen is touched and the finger is not moving.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, only **changes** to the finger movement is recorded. Put down  finger, lift up finger and dragging around triggers event.

Answer (score 0):

However, you could do

```
 e.phase == "began"
```

in your event function. That would be triggered when the user puts his finger on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Touch events are handled in phases. So the event being generated by the touch has "began", "moved", "ended" and "cancelled" phases. You could use detection, therefore, by doing this:

```
self.isTouched = false;

function defaultTouchHandler(e)
    if(e.phase == "began") then
        print("Tapped")
        self.isTouched = true;
        --User has touched the screen (not moving). Do "onMouseDown" things here
    elseif(e.phase == "moved") then
        print("Moved")
        --User is moving their finger wile touching. Do "onMouseMoved" things here
    elseif(e.phase == "cancelled" or e.phase == "ended") then
        print("End of touch")
        self.isTouched = false;
        --User lifted their finger, or an interrupt happened. Do "onMouseUp" things here
    end
end

self:addEventListener("touch", defaultTouchHandler)
```

When you then need to check if the screen is being touched, simply do:

```
if(isTouched) then
    --Screen is being touched
else
    --Screen is not being touched
end
```

EDIT: Obviously you can change "self" on the `addEventListener` line to be any object you wish to listen for touch events on

Answer (score 0):

```
local object = display.newImage( "ball.png" )
object.id = "ball object"

 local function onObjectTouch( event )
if ( event.phase == "began" ) then
    print( "Touch event began on: " .. event.target.id )
elseif ( event.phase == "ended" ) then
    print( "Touch event ended on: " .. event.target.id )
end
return true
end
object:addEventListener( "touch", onObjectTouch )
```